# Why remote tables and StaticLabels are still used in CloudHaskell?

Tags: haskell, cloud-haskell

I'm reading the source code of `distributed-process` and related packages.
In `distributed-static` we have the definition of `StaticLabel`:

```
data StaticLabel =
    StaticLabel String
  | StaticApply !StaticLabel !StaticLabel
  | StaticPtr SDynamic
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Typeable, Show)
```

Which is then used to define `Static` as a newtype wrapper around
`StaticLabel` with a phantom variable attached for type safety:

```
newtype Static a = Static StaticLabel
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Typeable, Show)
```

I have no questions about `StaticApply`, it just lumps together two static
values. However, `StaticLabel` and `StaticPtr` seem to achieve the same goal
in different ways.

If we go with `StaticLabel` we just have/transimt a `String` label which
then can be used to lookup a `Dynamic` value from `RemoteTable`:

```
newtype RemoteTable = RemoteTable (Map String Dynamic)
```

Where `Dynamic` is (defined in `rank1dynamic`):

```
data Dynamic = Dynamic TypeRep GHC.Any
```

Which is almost the same as `SDynamic` contained in `StaticPtr`:

```
data SDynamic = SDynamic TypeRep (StaticPtr GHC.Any)
```

The difference being, with `Dynamic` we have `GHC.Any` without indirection,
with `SDynamic` we must lookup the value. The result is the same: we receive
that `Any` value which we can `unsafeCoerce` if the target `TypeRep` is
[`instanceOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rank1dynamic-0.4.0/docs/Data-Rank1Typeable.html#v:isInstanceOf)
of the `TypeRep` we store in `SDynamic` or `Dynamic`.

Management of remote tables, although automated to some extent via TH, is
still kind of annoying, so why not use just `StaticPtr`s? Does `StaticLabel`
exist only for backward compatibility with older GHCs or am I missing
something?

Comment: I think you'll get a definitive answer if you [ask](https://github.com/haskell-distributed/distributed-static/issues/new) the [authors](https://github.com/haskell-distributed/distributed-static/graphs/contributors).

Comment: @Zeta, I did: https://github.com/haskell-distributed/distributed-static/issues/18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main reasons for doing that is that we had to have backwards compatibility and support 3 major versions of GHC. It was also not obvious if we want to jump in the static-pointers solution straight away. As for example their "stability" weaker. Basically the only guarantee is that for the same version of compiler, libraries and the same source-code - static-pointers will be compiled to the same value. Actually distributed-process was defined with that in mind, but some people want to have more stable pointers and static labels gives that as you can define your own rules for the label and have the same label even across the different executables.

If guarantees of the static pointers is enough for you, then there is [distributed-closure](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributed-closure) package, that provides a static-pointers based functions referencing. With this package you don't need to use remotetable at all and leave that only for the distributed-process internals and backward compatibility.